# How to test child components input property values passed correctly or not in angular unit testing

Tags: angular

I have a senario like based on JSON input component has  to dynamically render into the div/ ng template.

Each dynamic component will have some @input,  so will I test these @inputs passing correctly or not in unit testing.

This is the sample code:-
[Sample Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFSm8.png)

I was writing test case for this sample code snippet, How to check whether the input properties of the child component passed correctly or not, or at least I want to spy on these properties like how may times these properties has been calle (should we equal to ChildComponentCollection.length). is ther

Comment: Yes, you can test the `@Input`s in your unit tests if you wish. What is it you're asking?

Comment: What's is exactly your are asking?

Comment: sample code snippet added. please help me.